# jQuery Mobile + Backbone tap event fires twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, touch-event

Here's where I define the event in my view:

```
events : {
            "tap #exerciseProgressBarContainer" : 'progressBarClick'
        },
```

And here is the action:

```
    progressBarClick : function() {
        // start?
        if(this.curWorkoutExercise.isTimed() && !this.curExerciseStartTime) {
            HTMLHelper.endGlow(this.$('#exerciseProgressBarContainer .progressBar.overlay'));
            this.startExerciseProgressTimer();
        }
        // done?
        else {
            this.stopExerciseProgressTimer();

            // save the log
            this.addCurExerciseLog();

            this.startBreak();
            this.nextAction();
        }
    },
```

Basically, on the first tap, the user starts the progress timer, and after it's started, another tap finishes it. What's happening on my iPhone and my Android is the tap event fires **twice**, making the start and stop of the progress bar simultaneous. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it? Note: I've already tried swapping `tap` with `vclick`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up stopping the event propagation using
`e.stopPropagation()`
and
`e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the "touchend" event?

Btw. It's a good idea when your script fails when being fired while running to make sure it cannot be fired while running. What if someone tabs it twice because of impatience?

In some situations you can use jquery's function .one() for this. In most situations you want more flexibility and you can solve it with a simple variable check.